# Is this principle of internalization of external injections inconsistent?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Working in bi-sorted FOL, where lower cases stand for *sets* and upper cases for *classes*; add all axioms of ZF written completely in lower case, and add an axiom of Extensionality over all classes, and the following axioms:

$\forall x \ \exists Y: Y=x$

$\forall X \ \forall Y: X \in Y \to \exists z: z=X$

$\forall  \vec{Z} \ \exists X \ \forall y \ (y \in X \iff \phi(y, \vec{Z}))$; if $\phi(y, \vec{Z})$ is a formula not using $``X"$.

Define $V$ as the class of all sets.

Is there a clear inconsistency with the following principle?

Define recursively: $J_0``x = J(x) \\ J_{n+1} `` x= \{J_n`` y \mid y \in x \}$

**Internalization schema:**$n=1,2,... \\  \forall \text { infinite } x,y \ \exists J \ ( J: x \rightarrowtail y \land \forall s:  J_n ``s \in V )$

Where: $\text {infinite}(x) \iff \neg \exists \alpha \in \mathbb \omega_0 \exists f (f: x \rightarrowtail \{\beta \mid \beta < \alpha\})$; $``↣"$ is short for "injection"

Comment: Since you didn't include the axiom of choice, how are you defining "infinite"? Also, what is $\rightarrowtail$?

Comment: @MarkSaving, it's Tarski infinite, I will update the post. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you take x,y to be aleph numbers, e.g. aleph1, aleph0, and then by induction on aleph1 show that $J$ is a set, which will lead to inconsistency? e.g. If $J:\omega_1↣\omega$, let $j_0=\emptyset$ and for $\alpha\in\omega_1$ let $j_{\alpha+1}=j_\alpha\cup\{(\alpha, J(\alpha))\}$, and at limit points take the union. Every stage is a set, as well as the union of all stages. That union is injective iff $J$ is injective, which is impossible

Comment: @Holo, No! because set Replacement is fully written in set variables (lower case) , so you cannot use the upper case symbol $J$.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Where did I use replacement on $J$? $j_0$ is a set because it is the empty set, if $α∈ω_1$ then $J(α)∈ω$ so it is also a set, hence $(α,J(α))$ (from normal ZF arguments) is a set, so $j_{α+1}$ is a set. And if $β∈ω_1$ is limit, we can define the functional relation $φ$ such that $φ(x,y,β)⇔(x∈β\text{ and }y=j_{x})\text{ or }(x∉β\text{ and }y=0)$, this is a formula only on sets, then there exists a set $b$ such that $a∈b$ if and only if there exists $c∈β$ such that $φ(a,c,β)$, that is, $a=j_{α}$ for some $α∈β$.

Comment: @Holo, how can you prove that $j_\beta$ is a set? We don't have the symbol $j$ as a primitive constant, so when we come to define the functional relation that defines $j_\beta$ [for a limit $\beta$] we must put that for each $\alpha \in \omega_1$ we have $j_{\alpha+1}= j_\alpha \cup \{(\alpha, J(\alpha))\}$, but once this enters the definition of $j_\beta$, then we cannot prove it being a set, since its definition contains an upper case variable, that is $J$. The problem is in the definition of limit stages of $j$,, they'll always use the symbol $J$, thereby precluding proving them being sets.